# MySQL Unhandled Rejection Error, No Default

Tags: mysql, sql, database, reactjs, phpmyadmin

I'm using a React Social Network framework and I keep getting this error after signing up on it.

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'bio' doesn't have a default value
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/var/www/example.com/public_html/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/var/www/example.com/public_html/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/example.com/public_html/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (/var/www/example.com/public_html/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (/var/www/example.com/public_html/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/example.com/public_html/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/example.com/public_html/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:638:20)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/example.com/public_html/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (/var/www/example.com/public_html/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:200:25)
    at bcrypt.hash (/var/www/example.com/public_html/models/db.js:18:10)
    at /var/www/example.com/public_html/node_modules/bcrypt-nodejs/bCrypt.js:631:3
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  We'll need more information to help answer your question.  You said you get the error "after signing up on it".  How are you signing up, and where does this error appear?  i.e. in your command line, in your browser, etc.?  If this is happening in your command line, what's the exact command you entered?  If it's in your browser, are you familiar enough with that browser to open up its Network console and show us the request, including its params?

Comment: @RichieThomas I fixed the issue by just changing the default value. I'm battling another issue at the moment but unrelated with this one.

Comment: I just love the questions where people ask what to do, but the error message tells them **EXACTLY** what went wrong and why..

Comment: @N.B. Sorry I was just asking because I'm new to working with databases.

Comment: Come on.. you know and we know you haven't read the error because you probably assumed you won't get it. Now don't take this the wrong way - DO read errors, you CAN get it since you fixed it. This is the bad kind of lazy. You are supposed to be lazy but no when it comes to reading messages. Good luck in the future though.

Comment: @N.B. Yeah I tried fixing it and it didn't work for some reason so that's why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely are inserting a row in a (an unspecified) table, but you forgot to specify the value for the column `bio`.

Therefore, you are trying to insert a `null` value on the column `bio`, and this columns is most likely defined as `not null`.

Solution? Either:

1. Put some value on the `bio` column before inserting.
2. Change the table definition and add a `default` value for the column `bio`.